# Ajax Control Toolkit - Toolscriptmanager not available

Tags: compiler-construction, asp.net-2.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've been trying to get this asp.net 2.0 application up and running with little success. I removed all references and added the ajax control toolkit again and I'm still getting "ToolScriptManager:ID property not specified".

http://www.naeem.sarfraz.name/image001.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Check the **AjaxControlToolkit reference** in your project. If the AjaxControlToolkit is not in the Global Assembly Cache (C:\Windows\assembly), you have to set the "Copy local" property. Then the dll will be copied to the binary folder where it is needed during the execution of your web site/web app.